# Backbone View root element not added when using setElement

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am using the setElement to add a subview to an existing view. The problem I'm having is that the rootElement of the subview (tagName) is not being added, however its child elements are appended.

Main View:

```
  backbone.View.extend ({
    el:'.right-sec',
    initialize: function ()
    {
        this.subView = new SubView ();
        this.render ();
    },
    render: function ()
    {
        this.$el.html (view);
        this.assign (this.subView,".subview");
    },
    assign: function (view,selector)
    {
       view.setElement(this.$(selector)).render();
    },
});
```

SubView:

```
backbone.View.extend ({
    className:'sub-view',
    tagName:'div',
    initialize: function ()
    {
        this.collection = new ViewCol ();
        this.collection.on ("reset",this.render,this);
        this.collection.fetch ({reset:true});
    },
    render: function ()
    {
        this.collection.each (this.addView,this);
        return this;
    },
    addView: function (video,index)
    {
        this.$el.append (new View({model:video}).el);
    },
});
```

View:

```
 backbone.View.extend ({
    className:"pull-left",
    initialize: function ()
    {
        this.render ();
    },
    render: function ()
    {
        this.$el.html (_.template(ViewItem,this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
```

This is the html result:'

```
 <div class="right-sec">
      <div class="pull-left"><h2>Apple</h2></div>
      <div class="pull-left"><h2>Pineapple</h2></div>
      <div class="pull-left"><h2>Banana</h2></div>
 </div>
```

This is what I am expecting:

```
 <div class="right-sec">
    <div class="sub-view">
      <div class="pull-left"><h2>Apple</h2></div>
      <div class="pull-left"><h2>Pineapple</h2></div>
      <div class="pull-left"><h2>Banana</h2></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

What is causing the view to be rendered like this and what is the best way to fix it.

Comment: You have a typo: `className:'.sub-view'` should be `className:'sub-view'`.

Comment: Sorry about that it happened when I was creating the post. I'm going to edit.